# WPF Show MessageBox Asynchronously and Await

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to display a messagebox asynchronously and await.

I've built this nice function to run a synchronous method asynchronously on the UI thread. It works great for Window.ShowDialog, it works great for OpenFileDialog/SaveFileDialog.

With a MessageBox? It freezes. Why?

```
/// <summary>
/// Runs a synchronous action asynchronously on the UI thread.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="window">Any window to get the dispatcher from.</param>
/// <param name="action">The action to run asynchronously.</param>
/// <typeparam name="T">The return type of the action.</typeparam>
/// <returns>The result of the action.</returns>
public static Task<T> RunUiAsync<T>(this Window window, Func<T> action)
{
    if (window == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(window));
    TaskCompletionSource<T> completion = new();
    window.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => completion.SetResult(action())));
    return completion.Task;
}

public Task<MessageBoxResult> ShowMessageBoxAsync(Window owner, MessageBoxApiSettings settings) =>
    owner.RunUiAsync(
        () => System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
            owner,
            settings.MessageBoxText,
            settings.Caption,
            settings.Buttons,
            settings.Icon,
            settings.DefaultButton));
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` will always run on the UI thread no matter where you are. And there should be no trick required to run it in a new task and await.

Comment: Tried this and it works just fine on .NET Framework 4.7.2. Perhaps there's more to your particular scenario that's not shown here? Can you share a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: Messagebox.Show will block the UI thread. Please customize the messagebox window and use show to display the window

Comment: Can you try under Task.Run: 
Task.Run(() =>
{
  // your code here
});

Comment: The `MessageBox` is modal and expected to block until closed. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: There was something else indeed. In the MessageBox demo, I was calling ShowMessageBoxAsync().Result causing a deadlock. In the other demos, I had fixed that. It's working now :) thanks

Comment: @icode No, it won't block the thread. MessageBox only blocks it's parent window. If you have two separate windows in your application you can still use the other window.